# Terror In Islam

Tags: hadith-interpretation

Jihad, in the Quran is not a terror but in the Hadith, it is often found that its been mentioned that in order to establish Islamization, a Muslim has the sole right to create terror and disaster.
In today's world, why is it found that a Muslim is the sole culprit behind terrorism?

Whats the principle behind the formulation of the world's most disastrous terrorist groups ISIS, Al-Qaeda and many more militant groups. That claim they are following the words of Allah?

If that is the case then its certain that either Allah or Muhhammad (Peace and blessing be upon him) mentioned something or the other about the wrong teachings in the Quran or the Hadith?

Why do the Muslims follow the Quran as well as the Hadith simultaneously? Whats the true meaning of Muslim?
Is it not true that in today's world a Muslim do require to a process of mental rehabilitation process to this culture himself?

Comment: First of all, "Zihad, in Quran is not a terror but in Hadith", could you provide some examples? Also you have many questions here, it's better you focus on asking several different questions individually.

Comment: As written, this looks more like a rant than an actual *question*. We are not a typical Internet forum; questions here are expected to be clear, focussed, practical and answerable, not simply rhetoric to prove a point.

Answer (score 5):

While Islam is infamous in the media for suicide bombings, the Qur'an strongly condemns both murder and suicide.

> But **whoever kills a believer intentionally - his recompense is Hell, wherein he will abide eternally**, and Allah has become angry with him and has cursed him and has prepared for him a great punishment.  -- [Qur'an 4:93](https://quran.com/4:93)
>
> Because of that, We decreed upon the Children of Israel that **whoever kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the land - it is as if he had slain mankind entirely**. And whoever saves one - it is as if he had saved mankind entirely. And our messengers had certainly come to them with clear proofs. Then indeed many of them, [even] after that, throughout the land, were transgressors. -- [Qur'an 5:32](https://quran.com/5/32)
>
> Say, "Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He commands] that you not associate anything with Him, and to parents, good treatment, and do not kill your children out of poverty; We will provide for you and them. And do not approach immoralities - what is apparent of them and what is concealed. **And do not kill the soul which Allah has forbidden [to be killed] except by [legal] right.** This has He instructed you that you may use reason." -- [Qur'an 6:151](https://quran.com/6:151)

There are legal reasons to kill people, such as self defence, soldiers at war, or as punishment for murder.  (Personally, I disagree with the death penalty, but that's another story.)  Note also that terrorists kill believers and non-believers alike.

> O you who have believed, do not consume one another's wealth unjustly but only [in lawful] business by mutual consent. **And do not kill yourselves [or one another].** Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful. -- [Qur'an 4:29](https://quran.com/4:29)

and here's a relevant Hadith:

> The Prophet said, "Whoever purposely throws himself from a mountain and kills himself, will be in the (Hell) Fire falling down into it and abiding therein perpetually forever; and whoever drinks poison and kills himself with it, he will be carrying his poison in his hand and drinking it in the (Hell) Fire wherein he will abide eternally forever; and whoever kills himself with an iron weapon, will be carrying that weapon in his hand and stabbing his `Abdomen with it in the (Hell) Fire wherein he will abide eternally forever." -- [Narrated by Abu Huraira](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/76/90)

Basically, if you're a knowledgeable and genuine Muslim, there is no way you would do these horrible things as it's totally against the teachings of Islam.

> Islamic scholar Mohammed Abdelfadel, an expert at tracking ISIS propaganda, has found that the **agents of the group indoctrinate the recruits with very superficial and faulty knowledge of what is “haram and halal.”** He also says that the recruits are shown a very different picture of Islam with faulty and partial interpretations of Qur’anic verses. The lack of knowledge of Islam on part of the recruits makes them easy prey to these wrong teachings so that the Islam they follow is not the Islam of the Qur’an at all.  -- [World Religion News](http://www.worldreligionnews.com/issues/most-isis-recruits-actually-know-almost-nothing-about-islam)

Indeed, the Qur'an warns against "mischief makers":

> And of the people are **some who say, "We believe in Allah and the Last Day," but they are not believers.  They [think to] deceive Allah and those who believe**, but they deceive not except themselves and perceive [it] not.  In their hearts is disease, so Allah has increased their disease; and **for them is a painful punishment** because they [habitually] used to lie.  And when it is said to them, "Do not cause corruption on the earth," they say, "We are but reformers."  Unquestionably, it is they who are the corrupters, but they perceive [it] not.  And when it is said to them, "Believe as the people have believed," they say, "Should we believe as the foolish have believed?" Unquestionably, it is they who are the foolish, but they know [it] not.  -- [Qur'an 2:8-13](https://quran.com/2:8)

So, in answer to your question:

> Whats the principle that runs behind the formulation of the world's most disastrous terrorist group ISI and that of Al Qaida and many more militant groups who claims that they are following the words of Allah?

I propose: (a) the leaders believe Allah's punishment does not apply to them; they are the mischief makers, pretending to be devout Muslims to attract followers, (b) when countries act in response to their crimes (such as via drone strikes, or by arguing for laws that disfavour Muslims), the leaders use that as evidence that the West is oppressing Islam and murder is justified as self defence, and to attract followers, and (c) the followers are ignorant of the Qur'an, and are kept that way deliberately.

Of course, it's a multifaceted and dynamic matter, involving e.g. arms trafficking, fighting for land and oil, regional disputes, and the Sunni-Shia divide.  (And perhaps psychology, e.g., [obedience to authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment).)  So, it's not going to be possible to answer the question in full, but hopefully you get the idea that the Qur'an unequivocally says no.

Moreover, Muslims say no.  They murder Muslims!!  They murder our friends and family members.  Muslims go to war and get killed in an effort to stop their atrocities.

Comment: It is deemed as a related/helpful verse of Quran as you remarked "Qur'an 4:93".

Answer (score -1):

The main source of reference is Islam is Al-Quran. 
Hadith is the second source and thousands of Hadith are narrated. 
Hadith need to be studied carefully since it may be trusted or not. 
Hadith should be compared and strengthen with what was taught in Al-Quran.

If Hadith is contradict with Al-Quran, then it may falls into false or misleading hadith.

Before understanding hadith, one need to learn and well verse of how to read and interpret Al-Quran.

Prophet Muhammad has been practicing Al-Quran since he got the first Ayah. While he's doing must be supported by Al-Quran and he will not do something against Al-Quran.

Al-Quran also was sent to him based on Asbab (reason). Thus there are stages and development of how Al-Quran was sent down. There are strategies behind all what Prophet Muhammad has done.

There are two phases of development during Muhammad's life, in Mekah and Madinnah.

In Mekah, Muhammad have faced a lot of challenges from his friends and family. He preached and gathered from his closest family and friends with basic preaching of the true religion of worshipping Allah. Basic teaching is to acknowledge Allah is the only God, other deity and idols are false, improve the relationship within family (i.e. husband and wife, children and parents) and also relationship among humans (i.e. against slavery, killing of children).

With Muhammad challenging and endangering the idols, deity, tradition as well as position of pagan people of Makkah, he was threaten and cast away from his hometown. Negotiation and talks also have been done between the governors of Makkah i.e. Abu Lahab/Jahal which are also his uncle but nothing was accepted to implement Islam in Makkah. Tribal wars happened due to attempt to stop and kill Muhammad.

Thus Muhammad has to find other places that can accept Islam System, which then Madinah peoples willing to accept Islam.

Muhammad was trusted as leader, and he started to develop Madinah and it's people to follow Islam and every aspect. However, people of Makkah still see this as a threat and they started to attack Madinah. War couldn't be avoided and Muhammad, Muhajirin and Ansar has to defend the city.

After several wars, Muslim of Madinah has won most of them and gain strength time by time. The islam system implemented was proven just, and effective which attracted more people to come and stay in Madinah. Everybody from various races and tribes have felt the justice and goodness of Islam System. Several tribes have agreed to live under rule of Islam and Madinah.

When Muslim wanted to enter Makkah for doing Hajj, they was stopped by people of Makkah. Then a treaty of Hudaibiyah was established to list out several do's and don't between people of Makkah and Madinah so that Muslim can enter Makkah in peace to perform Hajj in specific time. With this treaty also, war and killing should be stopped between Makkah and Madinah.

But, people of Makkah later has broken the treaty by attacking and killing a tribe of Muslim people of Madinah. This was seen as a major breach of trust by Nabi Muhammad and Muslim in Madinah.

After this event, the next Ramadhan, Muslim of Madinah gathered in a large number to enter Makkah. The objective is to enter Makkah and stop the pagan system, unjust and cruelty of people in Makkah. with the large numbers, it just shows the strength of Muslim which sent message to the people of Makkah - "We have the strength if we are going to war". So while they enter Makkah, nobody dares to fight them.

Makkah was taken over by Muslim since people has seen how good and peaceful of Islam System in Madinah - no doubt. They are actually willing to have Islam implemented in Makkah and bring back the true religion that has been brought by Ibahim, Ismail and earliest prophet. Only the leaders of Makkah, of course always wanted to retain their wealth and position.

---

Conclusion: 
Al-Quran was sent down with reasons. Ayah Al-Quran has to be compared with Sirah/History of Prophet of Muhammad.

Then you will see, why at certain point, Muslim was been asked to involved in war.

Sometimes the war itself does not mean killing others, it's just a war within yourself - to fight the badness within you.

If you read Verse 7 of Surah Ali Imran (3:7), God has made clear statement that for those who wanted deviation, they just made their own interpretation - suitable for them but not suitable to Allah.

So, we need to know what God's want, the objectives of Islam, the strategies by example of Prophet Muhammad from pure heart so that we can interpret Al-Quran justly and correctly.

Alhamdulillah and praise to Allah for all knowledge He has given.